# In Suitescript I am trying to filter records by minutes using nlobjFilter and a datetime variable. Anyone have experience with this?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, netsuite, suitescript

A saved search UI in Netsuite has a choice to add minutes to date filter. In suitescript we are building our own filter and passing a date parameter with set minutes to the saved search to return only records that were created in the past 15 minutes. The filter is not working and returning us all records that were created the entire day. We have done a vast amount of debugging on the date variables and the minutes are being set properly but from what I can tell not being picked up in the nlobjFilter being passed to the saved search in suitescript.

Has anyone tried to create a date nlobjFilter in suitescript that filters by minutes? If so, how did you set your minute parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to filter by minutes in Suitescript 2.0:

```
var mySearch = {};
var type = 'vendorbill';
var columns = ['internalid'];

var filters = [];
filters.push(['custbody29', 'after', ["minutesago15"]]);

mySearch.type = type;
mySearch.columns = columns;
mySearch.filters = filters;
var mySearchObj = SEARCHMODULE.create(mySearch);
```

Comment: I believe all of the "__agoXX" filters are now marked as Deprecated. They may still work for a time, but could be discontinued at any point. Reference: NetSuite Help page titled "Search Date Filters"

Comment: @Adolfo Garza - your response was very helpful. Where did you find the minute filters? I am in need of one more minute filter for finding transaction records created in 15 minute segment.
 `var filters = [];`
`filters.push('datecreated', null, 'within', ["minutesago15", "___right now? "];`

Or maybe something like:



            
`filters.push('datecreated', null, 'after', ['minutesago15'];`
`filters.push('datecreated', null, 'before', ['__now']));`

Comment: @erictgrubaugh the Netsuite Help page titled 'Search Date Filters' has no reference of minute filters at all. It does have some deprecated date filters but none with minutes. I can't seem to find date minute filters anywhere in Netsuite Help pages, if you do find them please let me know.

Comment: @AshleyMillen I created a saved search using the UI with datetime field relative to 15 minutes ago and then loaded the search using suitescript and stringified the search object to look at the filters.